# Azure Active Directory - SSO w/ Multi-Tenant with non AAD IdP

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

Trying to get my head around using the latest portal Azure Active Directory for a multi-tenant federated identity solution.

For example, wish to set up a sample web app that essentially redirects the user to an Identity Provider (i.e. SAML 2.0 token server such as SSOCircle).

Should be a common scenario but I am not seeing helpful guides anywhere.

This "seems" close:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/

But is actually just multi-tenant with only Azure ADs, not a 3rd party.

Azure AD B2B seems to "the way to go", but again, I'm not finding helpful guides.

Any advice or suggestions on where to start would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure AD multitenancy system is predicated on all participants having an Azure AD tenant, given that it relies on the 1) the endpoints following the exact same behavior, modulo parameters that differentiate across orgs and 2) apps relying on a common identity configuration backend, which allows dynamic provisioning with a simple user consent operation (as opposed to the federated provisioning required when you can't rely on such a common base).
Azure AD B2C will allow you to aggregate multiple identity providers, supplying you with a single integration point. Whether that qualifies as multi tenant will depend on how you leverage the feature; out of the box, that's more similar to a classic federation provider/intermediary role. For more details, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom.